Integrating DBT Semantic Layer to LLM
I’m working on a Django application where I want to enable natural language querying capabilities using an OpenAI language model (LLM) like GPT-3. To structure and simplify the database access, I plan to use a DBT (Data Build Tool) semantic layer.
My goal is to allow users to ask questions in natural language, which are then translated into SQL queries through the LLM, utilizing the semantic definitions provided by DBT. This setup should ideally support complex queries across multiple tables, leveraging the relationships and dimensions defined in the semantic layer.
Here’s a brief outline of the setup:
1.  Django Application: Serves the frontend and backend, managing user requests.
2.  DBT Semantic Layer: Defines the data models, metrics, and relationships.
3.  OpenAI LLM (e.g., GPT-3): Used for interpreting natural language inputs and generating SQL queries.
4.  PostgreSQL Database: The source of data queried and managed via DBT.

Specific Questions:
1.  How should I integrate the DBT semantic layer within the Django app? Should the semantic layer be exposed via an API, or is there a more integrated approach?
2.  What are the best practices for using an LLM to generate SQL queries from natural language, especially using the constructs defined in the DBT models? How can I ensure that the queries generated are efficient and secure?
3.  Are there any existing libraries or frameworks that facilitate the integration of LLMs with DBT or similar semantic layers? If not, what should be the focus while building this integration?

Any guidance, examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated! I’m particularly interested in hearing about similar experiences or challenges faced in such integrations.
Thank you!
I tried Creating the Semantic models
aggreement.sql
select
    Agreement_Type_Code,
    Agreement_Name,
    Agreement_Original_Inception_Date,
    Product_Identifier
from 
    dbt_cdw_benchmark__seed.agreement

agreement.yaml
semantic_models:
  - name: agreement
    model: ref('agreement')
    entities:
      - name: agreement_type_code
        type: primary
      - name: product_identifier
        type: foreign
    dimensions:
      - name: agreement_name
        type: categorical
      - name: agreement_original_inception_date
        type: time
        type_params:
          time_granularity: day


Ideally, you should isolate DBT (Transformation layer), GPT3 customisation  and Django app and keep them separate.
DBT (Transformation layer)
Here we can manage reading the source data, perform transformations and calculate metrics.
It will be scheduled separately to run a given schedule. or can be triggered when necessary.
GPT3
To customise GPT-3 using a specific dataset, you'll need to fine-tune the model. Fine-tuning involves training the model on a dataset tailored to your use case, which helps the model learn specific patterns and responses relevant to your needs.
Steps:

pip install openai

Obtain OPENAI API key

Prepare dataset: Your dataset should be in JSONL format, where each line is a JSON object with "prompt" and "completion" fields.
 {"prompt": "Customer: I recently purchased a product from your website, but it arrived damaged. What should I do?\nAgent:", "completion": " I'm sorry to hear that. Please send us a picture of the damaged product, and we'll arrange for a replacement or refund."}
 {"prompt": "Customer: Can I return a product I bought last month?\nAgent:", "completion": " Yes, you can return it within 30 days of purchase. Please visit our return portal to start the process."}


Use OpenAI's API to upload your dataset.
 import openai

 openai.api_key = 'your-api-key'

 # Upload the dataset
 response = openai.File.create(
 file=open("dataset.jsonl"),
 purpose='fine-tune'
 )

 file_id = response['id']
 print(f"Uploaded file ID: {file_id}")


Once the dataset is uploaded, you can start the fine-tuning process.
 response = openai.FineTune.create(
   training_file=file_id,
   model="davinci"  # or another model you want to fine-tune
 )

 fine_tune_id = response['id']
 print(f"Fine-tune ID: {fine_tune_id}")


After the fine-tuning is complete, you can use the customized model to generate responses.
 def get_custom_response(prompt):
     response = openai.Completion.create(
         model="davinci:ft-your-custom-model-id",  
         prompt=prompt,
         max_tokens=150,
         temperature=0.7
     )
     return response.choices[0].text.strip()

 # Example usage
 prompt = "Customer: I recently purchased a product from your website, but it arrived damaged. What should I do?\nAgent:"
 response = get_custom_response(prompt)
 print(response)



Django App
This should only make a request to fine tuned gpt3 model to generate responses based on user prompt.

DBT is a tool that data engineers use to simplify

Ensure data quality (testing & freshness)
Documenting data pipelines
Ensuring data consistency
Reuse the datasets.

Our use case we don't need all these features we just need,
The documented definitions of data in YAML models.
For this instead of using DBT you can store this data in simple YAML file the way we store in DBT. This will help you in integrating seamlessly with the semantic model.
Generating a query from natural language text is more effectively accomplished using GenSQL. Opting for GenSQL over the OpenAI API is preferable because generative AI models works well when both inputs are text. For instance, if you have text data and a text-based question, generative AI would be the ideal approach.
but here your question is text and data is in tabular format.
A researcher at MIT recently published a paper on this
https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3656409
this uses a Generative Probabilistic model to query the data.
You can work further on this.
lastly on Django piece, once we have input text converted in SQL with GENSQL then we can generate queries in one module and in another module we can get structured results and present them with some contextual graphs with plotly and dash.
There is working model with this functionality based on RAG:
https://github.com/vanna-ai/vanna
